# SQL - Summarizing contents of a field per day based on a unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, unix, unix-timestamp

Can anybody help me out here, been ages since I played around with sql. :)

I've got a simple table;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consignmentstable` (
  `checktime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `consignments` smallint(6) NOT NULL
)
```

This table will be populated several times daily.

"checktime" will be populated with a unix timestamp (Field still needs to be int) and "consignments" will be populated with an INT.

I need an sql which summarize "consignments" for each day (checkdate).

The following example data is ranging from 2016-10-01 to 2016-10-06

```
checktime consignments
1475280000 528
1475366400 459
1475452800 10080
1475539200 7728
1475625600 7382
1475712000 6911
1475712015 11111
```

The two last here are both from 2016-10-06 and I'd like my output to summarize consignments per date as I will present the data in a graph. The output for the date 2016-10-06 above should in other words be 18022 (6911+11111)

Is it even possible considering I need the output to be INT and not any form of DATE? If so I would love some help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You want `from_unixtime()`:

```
select date(from_unixtime(checktime)) as dte, sum(consignments)
from consignmentstable
group by date(from_unixtime(checktime));
```

This takes the liberty of presenting the date as, well, a date.

If you *really* want the unix time stamp, you can convert it back using `unix_timestamp()`.